# Norm given by infimum on Vector Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be an $n$-dimensional real vector space and $span\left\{
v_{1},...,v_{m}\right\} =V$. The map $V\rightarrow 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
^{\geq 0}$, $x\rightarrow \left\Vert x\right\Vert =\inf \left\{
\sum_{i=1}^{m}\left\vert c_{i}\right\vert :\sum_{i=1}^{m}c_{i}v_{i}=x\text{
and }c_{i}\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{R}
%EndExpansion
\right\} $ defines a norm on $V$. Please show that the map holds norm axioms.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: Which axioms are you having trouble with?

Comment: (1) Write down the definiion of "norm".  (2) Check that this satisfies the definition ... In this forum, *you* first show your work, then we help you understand what went wrong.

Comment: If $\left\Vert x\right\Vert =0$, then $x=0$.